# D3js error with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

Hi I am trying to follow [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642), I use hard coded json:

```
var json = {
        "nodes": 
        [
            {
                "name": "Gosha",
                "url": "www",
                "center": true,
                "group": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Vlad",
                "url": "www",
                "center": false,
                "group": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Carmel",
                "url": "www",
                "center": false,
                "group": 1
            }
        ],
        "links": 
        [
            {
                "source": "0",
                "target": "1",
                "weight": 0.5,
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "source": "0",
                "target": "2",
                "weight": 0.6,
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "source": "1",
                "target": "2",
                "weight": 0.8,
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

And here is my js code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#sig").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(.05)
        .distance(100)
        .charge(-100)
        .size([width, height]);

    force
        .nodes(json.nodes)
        .links(json.links)
        .start(); //error on this line
```

I have this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined**

I think that the problem is related to the json (when I put the json from the example it works fine). I tried to validate my json - and it is valid.

Any  ideas?

Thanks,
Vlad

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the numbers in your source and target values.

Comment: Thanks that was the error!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           {
            "source": "0",
            "target": "1",
            "weight": 0.5,
            "value": 1
          }

 source and target should be number like this :

         {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 1,
            "weight": 0.5,
            "value": 1
          }
```